# AWS ECS - Images from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker

I am setting up an EC2 Container Service task but am looking use some private container images. Int the Docker Registry container, you can choose an interface to S3 as a storage backend. Is it possible to point a task definition image reference to an S3 bucket instead of a running a full private registry/hub? That would save me from having to run a little micro instance with a registry on it. It seems like this would be a thing since AWS services usually reference each other really well, but I can't find any info on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker images can be served at the moment ONLY with a private registry/hub and not as standalone even if you want to just use amazon s3 as backend so you have to run this registry somewhere and I believe you can use any cheap VPS other than amazon EC2 micro if you want to run it more cost efficiently but you HAVE to do this somewhere :)

Comment: It seems like you're right. This would be a nice complimentary service on AWS. Feature request!

Comment: I doubt either docker or amazon will be willing to provide this feature though , as it actually helps both companies financially if there is no such feature as docker sells private repos and amazon would love you to run another instance :)